# What does the HTTP column under Chrome Developer Tools Network tab, Request Cookies mean?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I have always used the Application tab of Chrome Developer Tools to check if my cookies are set to HTTP Only:
[image]

When I go to the Network tab and check the individual requests the cookies are also listed there but the HTTP flag is not checked:
[image]

What is this HTTP column under here trying to convey? When I type `document.cookie` in the console it returns an empty string so my cookies do appear to be HTTP only.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the ones that are coming back on the response as `Set-Cookie`.

Comment: Wouldn't they be listed under "Response Cookies" if they were the ones coming back on the response? The ones I'm referring to in my second screenshot are under "Request Cookies". There is nothing listed under "Response Cookies".